# hokuyo UTM-30LX-EW laser scanner: problems to detect

Tags: laser, urg-node, hokuyo-node, hokuyo, scanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys I'm having problems to detect hokuyo UTM-30LX-EW Laser Scanner. I followed the guide installation on wikiros and first I installed the hokuyo_node (actually I tried also with other package, urg_node). The problem is in the second step: I insert the Ethernet cable and when I search the laser into dev/  I don't find it. I found dev/tty0, dev/ttyS0 etc.. but not dev/ttyACM0 as is described in the guide. How I can detect the laser?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212527/hokuyo-utm-30lx-ew-laser-scanner:-problems-to-detect/) by [enri](https://answers.ros.org/users/22986/enri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-06-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the Hokuyo UTM-30LX-EW connected through ethernet, you can use the [urg_node](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node), setting the **ip_address** parameter value. Default factory Hokuyos come with IP 192.168.0.10.

```
rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:=192.168.0.10
```

-- Edit 1:

PC and laser must be on the same net 192.168.0.XX. Then, you should be able to ping the laser first,

```
ping 192.168.0.10
```

-- Edit 2:

If it does not work on a PC with IP 192.168.0.XX, maybe your Hokuyo laser has a different IP address.

To be sure, you can reset the laser IP address to the default one (192.168.0.10), following the instructions from the Laser [specification](https://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/download/pdf/UTM-30LX-EW_spec_en.pdf) (last page, *section 9 - Ethernet settings - IP Initialization* ), provided at the Hokuyo [webpage](https://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/download/products/utm-30lx-ew/).

If you manage to make it work with the default IP address but then you need to work in a different sub net, in the Hokuyo [webpage](https://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/download/products/utm-30lx-ew/) there is a tool (for Windows) to change the laser IP address.

---

Originally posted by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) with karma: 738 on 2015-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [enri](https://answers.ros.org/users/22986/enri/) on 2015-06-30**:
`[ERROR] [1435675488.414973920]: Error connecting to Hokuyo: Could not open network Hokuyo: 192.168.0.10:10940 could not open ethernet port.`

this is what the command returns

**Comment by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) on 2015-06-30**:
Reading this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/62830/hokuyo-utm-30lx-ew-not-detected-in-ubuntu-or-pc/), they basically say your computer and the laser must be on the same net (192.168.0.XX).

**Comment by [enri](https://answers.ros.org/users/22986/enri/) on 2015-07-01**:
Unfortunately I cannot fix that problem, I have already read all the post that I found.
This afternoon I try with this other guide: [http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/wiki/index.php/3._Using_a_hokuyo_LIDAR_with_ROS]
In this guide I don't change the IP!

thanks fherrero for the help!

**Comment by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) on 2015-07-01**:
That guide looks a bit old (ubuntu 10 and ROS Fuerte). I recommend you to reset the laser IP address (see Edit 2 of my answer) and continue trying with urg_node

**Comment by [enri](https://answers.ros.org/users/22986/enri/) on 2015-07-03**:
**Thanks fherrero for the advices,
Finally it works!! I had to initialize it manually!**

**Comment by [zlg9](https://answers.ros.org/users/46453/zlg9/) on 2021-05-18**:
My Hokuyo UST-10LX does not reset when connecting COM- to IP-RESTART for +2 second. Actually I cut those two wires (light blue and gray) and made a solid contact for several time, each more than 2 second. LED remains solid blue and does not blink. I don't have the existing IP address to work with the LiDAR. Any Idea ?